# How can I configure Visual-Stuidio to build my solution by copying a specific folder in the output directory?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, powershell, build

I want to create a folder in TFS where I will put all my PowerShell Modules and Snapins.

What should I do in Visual Studio in order to have a solution to be build by having this 'Modules folder' to be copied in to the bin directory?

For example if the modules are in C:\Source\PSModules\MyModules folder.

And if I create a 2 new solutions in VS that is SolutionFoo.sln and SolutionBar.sln.

How can I reference C:\Source\PSModules\MyModules folder from SolutionFoo.sln and SolutionBar.sln and configure it to have this folder to be copied into the Build directory?

Comment: You could always create a post-build event to copy the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a post-build event on the particular project to copy the contents of the modules folder from one solution to the other.